# Selection in PDF files

Tags: pdf, latex, pdf-generation, pdflatex

I'm working on an ebook conversion script.

When I create a PDF file using emacs `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` and then `ps2pdf`, I can select the words one by one on my ebook (Sony PRS 600). Same when I use Microsoft Word to print to PDF.

Yet, when I create a PDF using `pdflatex`, or `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`, I can't select but blocks of words, separated by punctuation signs.

It seems that there is something in the structure of the PDF files generated by latex that ebooks don't understand -- but what?

Do you know a switch to tell latex to behave properly, or a workaround?

Thanks!
CFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latex doesn't use a white space character to separate words. That's the problem.